Updating symbology of layer using selected features of another layer and table linking the two
I would like to come up with a visualization scheme for a connectivity matrix. I have two sets of polygons, and a table that shows the connections between them. I want to create a symbology using the is_selected() function such that each polygon is colored by the sum of connections to it from all of the selected cells. E.g. if Layer 1 has polygons a, b, and c and Layer 2 has polygons w, x, y, and z, that are connected like this:




w
x
y
z




a
2
1
1
0


b
2
1
2
2


c
1
1
2
3



and polygons b and c are currently selected in Layer 1, I would like to have Layer 2 color polygons w as a 3, x as a 2, y as a 4, and z as a 5.
